# Method in actionListener is not invoked after validation failed

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, actionlistener

I have a command Button that calls a method from the Session Scoped Bean if the inputs are valid.

```
     <h:form id="mainform">
            <p:panel id="panelform" header="Email Extractor"  >        
                <h:panelGrid id="formulaire" columns="2">  
                    <h:panelGroup id="formblock" layout="block" >
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:outputLabel for="Keyword" value="Keyword: " />  
                            <p:inputText id="Keyword"   type="search" requiredMessage="Keyword is required"
                                         value="#{mailMB.keyword}" required="true" label="Keyword">    
                            </p:inputText>                                                     
                            <p:outputLabel for="Emailsnbr" value="Enter the emails'number:" />  
                            <p:inputText  id="Emailsnbr"   type="number"  requiredMessage="Emails number is required" validatorMessage="Enter a number"
                                          value="#{mailMB.number}" required="true" label="Emailsnbr"> 
                                <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="1" maximum="53500" />
                            </p:inputText> 
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid> 
                <p:commandButton   value="Extract" style="width: 12%;height: 100%" update="tableemails, :confirmPurchaseTest, :mainform" id="extractbutton" ajax="true" widgetVar="ButtonExtract"
                                   actionListener="#{mailMB.searchEmails()}" onstart="blockUIWidget1.show();" oncomplete=" blockUIWidget1.hide(); if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) confirmDialog.show();" />    
                <p:dialog widgetVar="blockUIWidget1" modal="true" closable="false" resizable="false"  >  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">   
                        <div>
                            <p:graphicImage url="pictures/loading81.gif" width="200" height="200" alt="animated-loading-bar"/>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Please wait..."/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p:button    outcome="home" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w" title="Back To Home"   style="margin-right: 5px;white-space: nowrap" />  
                        </div>

                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:dialog>
            </p:panel>  
            <p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowIndex" id="tableemails" value="#{mailMB.mails}"  var="item" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                         paginator="true" rows="5" styleClass="case-table"  emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                         filteredValue="#{mailMB.filteredMails}" rowKey="#{item.id}" 
                         selection="#{mailMB.selectedMail}" selectionMode="single" >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":mainform"/>
                <p:column styleClass="blockable">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Email"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.email}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
 <p:confirmDialog closable="false" style="position: absolute;  width: 50px; border-color: blue" id="confirmPurchaseTest"  message="Your Database was successfully created. It contains #{mailMB.number} Emails "  
                             appendToBody="true"                                                             
                             header="Get Emails List" severity="info" widgetVar="confirmDialog"> 
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton id="getEmails" style="width: 35%;height: 100%" value="Get Emails" oncomplete="window.location.href = '/Hitonclick/emailsList.xhtml'"  >
                        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{mailMB.preRender}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton id="declineTest" style="width: 35%;height: 100%" value="Decline" onclick="deleteDialog.show();" /> 
                </h:form>
            </p:confirmDialog>
```

My SessionScoped Bean is

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mailMB")
@SessionScoped
public class MailManagedBean implements Serializable {
@Inject
private MailBusinessLocal mailmanagerLocal;
@Inject
private DataBusinessLocal dataBusinessLocal;
@Inject
private CustomerBusinessLocal customerBusinessLocal;
```

.....

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mails = new ArrayList<>();
     }
    public void searchEmails() throws Exception {
        idCustomer = (String) session.getAttribute("idCustomer");
        System.out.println(idCustomer + " this is it");
        Customer customer = customerBusinessLocal.findById(idCustomer);
        data = dataBusinessLocal.createData(new Date(), number, keyword, moteur, customer, State.REJECTED);
        mails = mailBusinessLocal.createEmails(keyword, number, moteur, data);
        System.out.println("Method was invoked");

    }
}
```

if i enter 0 in the emails's number input for exemple and submit with Extract command Button for the first time i get the validatorMessage So i enter a valid number and submit again. And here comes the problem,  the dialog in the oncomplete is shown without invoking the method in the actionListener. I mean i get the confirm dialog of persisted object without invoking the method that persists the object. Am i missing something??
How could i fix that?

Comment: Is it a copy paste code? Why is there a new open form at the end.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 it's just a miss written.

Comment: for me it works. Have you debug it? Are you sure that the app dont call the method?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Yes it's not invoked, i'm using logger. Plus i've noticed that the inputs are intialized to empty in the second submit.

Comment: hmm... can you post the full bean and xhtml ? And which version of primefaces you use?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 i'm using primefaces 3.5

Comment: I cant reproduce the table but without it works for me as excepted. Can you try to delete the table (for test) and try again?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 in fact the method called in the button extract search emails according to the number and keyword entred. After this it persists the emails list and displays them in the datatable.

Comment: okay, it works without table? ... Than make a own form for it or add this to the button "process="panelform"